# json request gets cancelled when skipping to next page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I am using json to get the list of user information to show on the top of the page using jquery in asp.net (C#) application.

i am using jquery timer plugin for the json call to check for the user information frequently(for every 15 minute when the user is in online).

When the json request is in progress, and when i navigate to the next page, the json request gets cancelled/stops, which can be clearly seen using firebug in mozilla.

How to keep the json call going till it gets its response?

Comment: If you're not on that page any more, what would you do with the results of the Ajax call, even if it weren't cancelled?

Comment: Did you accidentally submit the question form twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604906/json-request-gets-cancelled-when-skipping-to-next-page

Comment: I need to show it on the top of the page, regardless of the user's current page. The user can be in any page, but i need to show the information on top top of the user's staying page

Comment: i think so, i have deleted the other post

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  If you're going to a new page, will that new page request the information as well?  If so, why do you need the response from the original page?

Comment: The request will be from the master page and the information also will be shown in <div> of master page which is common for all pages. The request will be sent every 15 min. from mater page, but my concern is when a particular json request is in progress, it gets cancelled when the user moves to the next page and the user will get the information after 15 more minuntes only.

Comment: If the info is in the div of the master page then it will be updated with the current information when navigating to another page (unlesss by 'another page' you mean an AJAX request).

Comment: No. Its not updating. The json request gets cancelled and the user has to wait for other 15 minutes to get the informations

Answer (score 1):

Based on the copious comments I've seen, I'd suggest one of the following:

**Option 1**:

- In the master page, call the function that requests the information in a json call straight away.  This means that whenever the page changes, it requests the new information.
- Keep your 15min interval just in case the user sits on the same page for 15min.

**Option 2**:

Use AJAX partial updates to update only the main contents of the page.  If the browser isn't requesting entire new pages, the code in the masterpage never actually gets refreshed.  This sounds like it's how you expected the site to behave, but it's a lot of rework to actually get this happening.

**Explanation**:

I think the major misunderstanding here is what happens when a user navigates to a new page.

You may have heard before that the web is stateless.  What that means is that when you're on a web page and you navigate to a new page, the entire contents of the page you're on are discarded, and the server hands you a brand new page - top to bottom.  None of the html in the original page is kept.

Using master pages doesn't change anything.  Master pages are really just used as wrappers on the server side so that it knows to include the header and footer in every page you send back.  You're still going to be sending back a completely new page.

What this means for your example is that cancelling the json request is the only sensible thing for the browser to do.  You've made an AJAX request for some information, and while it's waiting for a response, the user has navigated to a new page.  The browser knows that the server will deliver a brand spanking new page with completely new html, so it throws out the current page.  The div that was going to be updated literally doesn't exist any more.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the AJAX request around for a page that is no longer open doesn't make sense, as there's nowhere for the response handler to display results.

Create a header that's included on every page. When the page is loaded, the header should display the current values. Start a new AJAX request when the new page is opened.

Comment: i'll have a <div> to the show the content in my master page(not on a specific page).

Comment: @Prasad - you can't think of a master page as a separate page from a client's point of view.  The master page and its contents are delivered in one hit as if it's one response.  Navigating generates and entire new page - nothing stays on the client's side.

Comment: All the variables within a script are scoped to a specific page as viewed in the browser ("global" variables are actually properties of `window`). It's the URI that determines whether two pages are the same, not the script that generates a page. Change the URI (excepting the fragment ID) and you get a new page, losing access to all old variables.